# VSCode Hover Provider - Remove default info/title?

Tags: javascript, api, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Im writing a language server for ExtJs using HoverProvider among other things, I've written other extensions including Task Explorer, but cant for the life of me figure out if there's a way to remove the default hover information, the word "any" that VSCode injects on all the properties and functions within the file.

See attached screenshot.

I guess since the js language servers cant read ExtJs class definitions (json object as a function expression), I get this "any" text on everything, I'd like to replace it or remove it somehow, is it possible?  I can properly insert my doc, but that "any" is still there...

Hover info screenshot with the word "any" at the top

[image]